# BAD GATEWAY 502 Error from Windows Live Writer

Tags: windows-live-writer

Using Windows Live Writer, I've been updating my blog (link in profile if you're interested - I won't spam it here), which runs Wordpress 3.6.1 on Debian Wheezy 7.1. I had ensured that `/var/lib/php5` has 1775 permissions on the server, and gracefully restarted Apache2; no change.

I can access the blog just fine, and the control panel, from both Internet Explorer, and Firefox. Other people admit they can also access it, so I know the blog itself is up and running.

I also tried re-setting up my blog in WLW. It detects the blog, and settings, but still won't let me post! What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there was a proxy issue. At my location, I run a Squid3 Proxy on Debian, and it kept giving me the '502 BAD GATEWAY' message. When I disabled the System Proxy, and the proxy settings on the site account and WLW's Options, then I could post OK.

Before I disabled the proxy, I was running a `tail -f /var/log/apache/www.talk-about-it.ca/*.log`, which shows me the last 10 entries of both the `access.log` and `error.log` files, and follows them as they update. With the proxy turned on, I would get ONE single hit. When I disabled the proxy, I could see both were scrolling up as it posted the items to my blog.